# Firestore Error "No federated protocol supports the incoming VerifyAsssertion" for twitter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=application_key_from_firestore`

with help of postman

Header contains: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Body I have selected binary and pasted below in file

```
    '{
       "postBody":"access_token=[access_from_twitter]&oauth_token_secret=[secret_from_twitter]&providerId=[twitter.com]",
        "requestUri":"[https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler]",
        "returnIdpCredential":true,
        "returnSecureToken":true
   }'
```

I am getting error

```
No federated protocol supports the incoming VerifyAsssertion
```